# CSV file into a python list is not completely imported

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, io

i want to read a csv file into a python list.
sometimes, it produces an `IOError: [Errno 0]`

i have searched a lot and tried to use flush() or seek(0,1) functions.
i am using the csv built-in module in python.
also, i used pandas.read_csv.
but always, the list in not complete sometimes.
i am working on windows 10 machine, with python2.7 64-bit.
here is my code:

```
import csv
from io import open

j = 0
k=0
csv_filename = 'G:\work and courses\Medrar\heirarchies\hier1.csv'
directories_lst = []

def fn():
    global j
    global k        
    global directories_lst
    try:
        csvFile = open(csv_filename,'r')      
        directories_lst=[row for row in map(list, csv.reader(csvFile))[1:]]
        csvFile.close()
        for i in directories_lst:
            try:
                print i    
            except:
                k = k+1
    except:
        j = j+1        
        fn()
```

when that function ran for about 1000 times, it produces like 300 exceptions, at the body of the for loop.
everybody say that it is a problem with python io module implementation in windows.
i need a workaround to solve that problem.
that all the content of my .csv file. (it is just a sample)

```
folder_1,folder_2,folder-3,folder_4
f1,f12,f121,f1211
f1,f13,f131,f1311
f1,f11,f111,f114
f1,f14,f141,f1414
f1,f15,f151,f1514
f2,f21,f212,f2124
f2,f22,f222,f2224
f2,f23,f232,f2324
f2,f24,f242,f2424
f3,f31,f313,f3134
f3,f32,f323,f3234
```

Comment: my guess is that the file path is not valid, try scaping the slash symbol: `csv_filename = 'G:\\work and courses\\Medrar\\heirarchies\\hier1.csv'`

Comment: @hir12111
i have tried it, but nothing changed!

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some small issues in my opinion.

```
import csv
from io import open

j = 0
k=0
csv_filename = 'G:\work and courses\Medrar\heirarchies\hier1.csv'
```

As already mentioned in the comments, try a raw string as shown below.

```
csv_filename = r'G:\work and courses\Medrar\heirarchies\hier1.csv'


directories_lst = []

def fn():
    global j
    global k        
    global directories_lst
    try:
        csvFile = open(csv_filename,'r')      
        directories_lst=[row for row in map(list, csv.reader(csvFile))[1:]]
```

If there's an exception in the line above, the code continues in exception handling, meaning your file isn't closed anymore.
Look at the ``with` statement for opening files.

```
        csvFile.close()
        for i in directories_lst:
            try:
                print i    
            except:
                k = k+1
```

I can't get the purpose of this block. You iterate over the elements of `directories_lst`, i don't know why print should fail.

```
    except:
```

Don't make exception handling without specifying the exception. Make smaller try - except blocks for specific failures.

```
        j = j+1        
        fn()
```

And why are you calling your function recursively? Iv you got *any* within the function, it would run forever.

So, try to open a file like this:

```
try: 
    with open(fname, 'r') as f:
        content = f.read
except IOError:
    print('File %s not found' % fname)
```

Comment: the
try:
except: 
block is just for testing
to caught the exception. i am iterating on directories_lst to get the file rows as items to work on in my code.
the exception is raised exactly when i am trying to read the items from that list.
the file open works fine, but not all the items in the file are retrieved. when the exception is raised, the items are incomplete.

Comment: Can you try the same code with python 3? Maybe it's encoding issue...utf-8, unicode?

Comment: i dont think that will make a difference, as this code is running fine sometimes and other times raising error (approx. 33% of time)

Answer (score 0):

Is you goal to have a list of lists for each row of your csv file, looking like

```
[[f1,f12,f121,f1211], [f1,f13,f131,f1311], [f1,f11,f111,f114], ... ]
```

If yes, do you also have an Error returned when using pandas ? For example the following script:

```
import pandas as pd
file = pd.read_csv('G:\work and courses\Medrar\heirarchies\hier1.csv')
main_list = []
for i, row in file.iterrows():
    folders_list = row.values.tolist()
    main_list.append(folders_list)
print(main_list)
```

Comment: thanks Damien,
it gets good results. but there is another error when i ran it many times  


print main_list
IOError: [Errno 34] Result too large

Comment: How big is your file?

Comment: it is approx. 1kb (less than 20 rows, four colums)